# Boids in compute shader: How can I avoid a stable state when processing every boid in parallel?

Tags: simulation, hlsl, compute-shader, boids, vvvv

I want to implement the simple, age-old boid algorithm in 2D but as compute shader in HLSL (host programm ist VVVV).
Now my problem: In all 2D sample-applications I`ve found, boids are updated one at a time. This results in some jittering that causes the typical "random" results. Direction changes, etc.

I am not sure if my implementation is correct, but if I test each rule individually, my results look like other references. If I apply the rules together however (in pretty much any combination), very soon my boids enter a stable state where they form a fixed formation and just fly in some particular direction. Changing the view-radius influences the size and number of formations but doesn`t introduce anything "chaotic" or flock like, just static bunches after a couple of seconds.

Is there an implementation problem or is this just a property of parallel compute you have to compensate (somehow?

Relevant code:

```
void CS(uint3 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID){
if (tid.x >= elementCount)
    return;
            

if(reset){
    OutputBuffer[tid.x].x =  random(float2(rand.x + 12,tid.x-4)); // PosXY
    OutputBuffer[tid.x].y =  random(float2(tid.x + 16,rand.y*6));
    OutputBuffer[tid.x].z =  random(float2(tid.x,tid.x * 2)) / 100; //VelXY
    OutputBuffer[tid.x].w =  random(float2(tid.x * 16, tid.x / 4))/ 100; 
}else{  
    
float maxSpeed = 0.01;      
float2 myPos = OutputBuffer[tid.x].xy;
float2 myVel = OutputBuffer[tid.x].zw;
float2 myAcc = 0;

float2 steerAlign = 0;
float2 steerCohesion = 0;
float2 steerAvoid = 0;
    
int    alignCount = 0;
int    cohesionCount = 0;
int    avoidCount = 0;
                
for(uint i = 0; i < elementCount; i++){ 
    if(i != tid.x){
        float2 iPos = OutputBuffer[i].xy;
        float2 iVel = OutputBuffer[i].wz;
    
        float dist = distance(iPos,myPos);  
        
        if(dist < range / 2){
            steerAlign += iVel;
            alignCount++;
        }
        
        if(dist < range * 3){
            steerCohesion += iPos - myPos;
            cohesionCount++;
        }
        
        if(dist < range){
            float2 diff = myPos - iPos;
            diff /= dist * dist;
            steerAvoid += diff;
            avoidCount++;
        }
    }   
}
    
    if(alignCount > 0 && steerAlign.x != 0){
        steerAlign /= alignCount;
        steerAlign = normalize(steerAlign) * maxForce;
    }
    
    if(cohesionCount > 0){
        steerCohesion /= cohesionCount;
        steerCohesion = normalize(steerCohesion) * maxForce;
    }
    
    if(avoidCount > 0){
        steerAvoid /= avoidCount;
        steerAvoid = normalize(steerAvoid) * maxForce;
    }

            
    if(myPos.x < -1){
        myPos.x = 1;
    }
    
    if(myPos.x > 1){
        myPos.x = -1;
    }
    
    if(myPos.y < -1){
        myPos.y = 1;
    }
    
    if(myPos.y > 1){
        myPos.y = -1;
    }
    
    myAcc = (steerAlign * alignFx) + (steerCohesion * cohesionFx) + (steerAvoid * seperationFx);
    myAcc = clamp(myAcc, -maxForce, maxForce);
    
    myVel += myAcc;
    myVel = clamp(myVel,-maxSpeed,maxSpeed);
    myPos += myVel;
    
OutputBuffer[tid.x].xy = myPos;
OutputBuffer[tid.x].zw = myVel;             
}
```

}